# MIPS, Recursion

Tags: mips

I trying to write a MIPS program that gets an unsigned integer as argument and returns the sum of all decimal digits in the integer recursively. For example if the argument is 75080 then the sum to be returned is 20 (7+5+0+8+0). Here is my code so far. Any help would be appreciated.

My way of thinking was to divide the number by 10 leaving me with the last integer in the number, add the reminder using mfhi.

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a string of integer: "
output: .asciiz "\nThe total sum is: "
    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la $a0, prompt
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    move $t2, $v0

    la $a0, output
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

Loop:
    div $t2, $t2, 10
    mflo, $t1
    mfhi, $t3
    beqz $t1, Exit
    add $t1, $t1, 0
    b additive

additive:
    add $t0, $t1, $t1
    j Loop

Exit:   
        la $a0, output
            li $v0, 4
            syscall
            la $v0, 10
            syscall
```

Comment: What OS is this where syscall 4 lets you print a prompt without giving a buffer length, and syscall 5 gets you input that's already converted to an integer?

Comment: I don't remember if MIPS is this way or not, but in some systems it matters which order the move from high and move from low commands come in, and if what little I remember about MIPS is actually correct, you might have gotten this backwards.

Comment: This is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031785/iteration-and-recursive-in-mips

Answer (score 0):

- What's this supposed to be doing? Adding 0 to the register won't change its value:

  `add $t1, $t1, 0`
- After dividing and copying to `$t1` and `$t3`, the *quotient* is in `$t1` and the *remainder* is in `$t3`. You're treating it the other way around when you add to the total.
- This is actually going to give you `$t0 = 2 * $t1`: you're adding `$t1` to itself and storing the result in `$t0`.

  `add $t0, $t1, $t1`

  You probably actually want:

  `add $t0, $t0, $t3`
- You're checking for `$t1 == 0` *before* adding the remainder to the total, so the most significant digit will never get added. You don't really need a subroutine for adding to the total either. You can also use `bnez Loop` instead of `beqz Exit` -> `b Loop`. Lastly, you don't even need `$t1`, because the quotient is already in `$t2`.

Get rid of `additive` and replace `Loop` with this:

```
Loop:
    div $t2, $t2, 10
    mfhi, $t3
    add $t0, $t0, $t3
    bnez $t2, Loop
```

- Your `Exit` is weird: you're printing the `output` string a second time instead of printing the integer.

Change it to this:

```
Exit:
    move $a0, $t0
    la $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach is quite simple. You need recursive function, I named it SumDigits that will take the last digit and repeat procedure for all digits in the argument. After the recursive call returns you'll add digit to the previous result. The code is commented for easier understanding. The code follows:

```
    .text

#calculates sum of digits recursively
SumDigits:

    sub     $sp,    $sp,    12                  #alloocate 12B on stack
    sw      $ra 0($sp)                      #save return address
    sw      $a0,    4($sp)                      #save argument

    beq     $a0,    $0, exit_sumdigits      #when there is no more digits return 0
    rem     $t0,    $a0,    10                  #get last digit
    sw      $t0,    8($sp)                      #save it on stack
    div     $a0,    $a0,    10                  #divide argument by 10
    jal     SumDigits                       #repeat procedure
    lw      $t0,    8($sp)                      #read digit from stack
    add     $v0,    $v0,    $t0             #add digit to previous result
    lw      $ra,    0($sp)                      #load return address
    addi    $sp,    $sp,    12                  #free stack
    jr      $ra                             #return

exit_sumdigits:
    li      $v0,    0                           #there are no more digits, return 0
    lw      $ra,    0($sp)                      #load return address
    addi    $sp,    $sp,    12                  #free stack
    jr      $ra                             #return

main:
    li      $a0,    75080                       #load number in $a0
    jal     SumDigits                           #call SumDigits

    move    $a0,    $v0                         #set a0 = result of SumDigits
    li      $v0,    1                           #set $v0 for print int system call
    syscall

    li      $v0,    10                          #set $v0 for exit system call
    syscall

.data
```